# What difference does WITH GRANT OPTION make?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to create a standard MySQL user but I couldn't understand the difference on between of these two statements.

```
1 -> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user@host WITH GRANT OPTION;
2 -> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO user@host;
```

Which one should I use for a standard user and what is the effect of the "WITH GRANT OPTION" to the creating a user?

Comment: See this -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html#:~:text=To%20grant%20a%20privilege%20with,grant%20any%20account%20any%20privilege.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALL` does not include `WITH GRANT OPTION`.  `WITH GRANT OPTION` allows the user to perform `GRANT` for other users.

Comment: so **WITH GRANT OPTION** lets the user to perform operations on other users ?

Comment: @EmrahTema - true.  Don't give that permission to the average person; it is a serious security issue.   `ALL ON *.*` is nearly as dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

WITH GRANT OPTION give the permission to the grantee to grant those permisisons to other users means it not only provide specified permission but also the authority for that user to pass the grant to other users.

So say DBA has provided Grant select on Table A to User X with grant option then User X can provide select Grant on Table A to user Y.